# Why is the control node affecting my camera3d movement in Godot 4.2

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

[image: Here is the camera movement code, right next to the control node]
The code for the controll node doesn affect the camera movement, just the control node itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us engage in the ancient art of reading the code....

---

Line 1:

```
extends Node3D
```

Tells us that this script will be attached to a `Node3D`. It also tell us that there will be `Node3D` nodes that extended by means of having this script.

---

Line 3:

```
@onready var player = $".."
```

Tell us that when the `Node3D` that has this ndoe attached becomes ready, we will initialize a variable `player` with a reference to the parent node.

This implies that the parent node is representing the player. And thus, we know that the `Node3D` that has this script attached is intended to be placed as a child of the player.

---

Lines 5 to 7 (ignoring comments):

```
func _ready():

    Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURE
```

This tells us that when the `Node3D` that has this script attached becomes ready, it will tell Godot to capture the mouse pointer in the game window.

*Which is not what the comment says*.

---

Lines 9 to 14 (ignoring comments):

```
func _unhandled_input(event):

    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        player.rotate_y(-event.relative.x * 0.01)
        rotate_x(-event.relative.y * 0.01)
        rotation.x = clamp(rotation.x, deg_to_rad(-90), deg_to_rad(90))
```

This tells us that when there is an input event that was not marked handled somewhere else, and that input event is the motion of the mouse, the script will tell Godot to:

- Rotate the `player` around the y axis (which is the vertical axis) proportionally to the horizontal motion of the mouse.
- Rotate the `Node3D` that has this script attached around the x axis... And also clamp that rotation to the range between `-90` degrees to `90` degrees.

*Despite what the comment says, no camera is involved.*

---

Thus, the code does not handle a camera.

Also, it appears that no camera is a child of the `Node3D` that has this code attached.

And that is why said `Node3D` does not affect the movement of your `Camera3D`.

---

I presume you would also be interested in how can you make it affect the movement of your `Camera3D`.

There are two simple ways:

- You can make your `Camera3D` a child of the `Node3D` that has this script attached, so that when it rotates, the `Camera3D` also rotates by virtue of being its child.
- Get a reference your `Camera3D` (which you might be able to do with the `$` syntax, or by getting it from `get_viewport().get_camera_3d()`) and move it similar fashion as the way the script manipulates `player`. This will give you more control over the motion of the `Camera3D`, but also means more ways you can get it wrong... And you need to write the code for what you want exactly.

There are also two less simple approaches:

- You can give the `Camera3D` another script, which will control its motion. Which might either use `_unhandled_input` itself... Or might get a reference to the `Node3D` that has this script attached (for example, using the `$` syntax) and copy the motion from it.
- And while we are talking about copying the motion of another `Node3D`... You might use a `RemoteTransform3D` to so for you. So you can set the `RemoteTransform3D` to move the `Camera3D`, and thus the `Camera3D` will move with the `Node3D` that has this script attached, without being a child.